# neo4j CSV Loading, Error: undefined - undefined

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 3.0 and loading a CSV, I have a fresh database and using a load CSV command. The files is about 7mb and 40k records. I have am also using the:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
```

I also have the CSV stored in the local server where neo sits. After about 5mins of loading my Database goes from 80kbs to 13mb's but I get the following error:

```
Code
 Error: undefined - undefined
```

I check the logs and don't anything in debug logs. I am not sure what might be going wrong? Is the file to large? its 40k records and I am expecting it to create a bit less than that in Nodes.

After the Load also the DB is continuing to grow in size. 
When it errors out it is at 13MB's now when I look it is at 24mb's. Is it just a connection error to the neo4j interface but in the background it is still processing?

Also this is sitting on an Amazon m4.4Xlarge, so plenty of Memory and CPU horsepower.

Comment: Maybe "Max Execution Time" value. Please check it from your setting.